# Adding Spacemacs documented layers fails

Tags: spacemacs, config

Adding layers existing in the layer section of the .spacemacs documentation results in failed test in the *dot-test-results* buffer generated after reloading the .spacemacs file (with `SPC-f-e-R`).

increminated layers were :
neotree ;; for filetree

notmuch ;; for emails

parinfer ;; clojure / lisp paren inference

pdf  ;; pdf visualisation

prettier

The * spacemacs* welcome screens gets some warnings but couldn't find any other error messages to help debug :

```
   Warnings:
           - Unknown layer neotree declared in dotfile.      
           - Unknown layer notmuch declared in dotfile.      
           - Unknown layer parinfer declared in dotfile.      
           - Unknown layer pdf declared in dotfile.      
           - Unknown layer prettier declared in dotfile.      
           - package twittering-mode not initialized in layer keyboard-layout, you 
             may consider removing this package from the package list or use the :toggle 
             keyword instead of a `when' form.      
           - package linum not initialized in layer nlinum, you may consider removing 
             this package from the package list or use the :toggle keyword instead of a `when' form.      
           - package linum-relative not initialized in layer nlinum, you may consider
             removing this package from the package list or use the :toggle keyword 
             instead of a `when' form.      
           - More than one init function found for package helm-make. Previous owner was ivy,
             replacing it with layer helm.      
           - More than one init function found for package smex. Previous owner was ivy,
             replacing it with layer smex.      
           - package evil-nerd-commenter not initialized in layer evil-commentary, you may
             consider removing this package from the package list or use the :toggle keyword
             instead of a `when' form.      
           - package vi-tilde-fringe not initialized in layer vim-empty-lines, you may
             consider removing this package from the package list or use the :toggle keyword
             instead of a `when' form.      
           - tern binary not found!
```

my config :
OS: mac osX Catalina 10.15.5
emacs : GNU Emacs 26.3 (build 1, x86_64-apple-darwin18.5.0, Carbon Version 158 AppKit 1671.4)
fetch with `brew install emacs-plus@26` IIRW

spacemacs à jour (latest)
271 packages loaded in 18.794s (e:202 r:2 l:18 b:49)

(this seems slow, may be because of spaceline-all-the-icons)

My .spacemacs is still a work in progress and thus not in a github repo yet so I attached a gist link  below.

Thanks for any hits on how to get thos layers working.

Best
Samusz

.spacemacs file: https://gist.github.com/samusz/2cfb1ced064276be06eee4488cc86788

Comment: I've got the same issue... unfortunately no solution yet?

Answer (score 1):

Found the issue for me... https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/issues/10840

It seems `pdf` used to be called `pdf-tools`. So I changed it to `pdf-tools` and it seems to work now.

---

**UPDATE:** *I was previously using the latest `master` but it looks like `master` is very old compared to `develop`. The latest release at the time **0.200** is even older. I've now moved branch to `develop` and the code seems to match the online documentation a lot better. It looks like the long time between releases has caused the documentation to diverge significantly from the latest release*

*So this is something else to check if you have this issue. It will hopefully get better when the upcoming **0.300.x** is released?*

Comment: Yes the 'develop' branch is a must ! I don't remember if I was on that branch a the time. It seems I was on 'latest' which is a misleading name. Best